# Estilos Responsive

Tags: html, css

Tengo el siguiente problema, en los estilos responsive, me funciona y se me adapta bien mi sitio web los tamaños `480px`, `768px`, y `1024px`, pero al momento de usar el `1600px`, este no me agarra o no funcionan los tamaños, alguien sabe porque puede ser?

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/6AZbc.png]

Comment: Podrías agregar un [snippet](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) de código que reproduzca el problema? Porque el código de la imagen no presenta ningún error

Comment: El .main__about... está afuera del corchete que cierra al media query de 1600px

Comment: si cuelga el codigo te podriamos ayudar , en la imagen  parentemente es que la clase .main_about esta afuera prueba en meter todo  dentro del media query 1600 px

Answer (score 4):

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En el siguiente ejemplo te muestra el comportamiento de los media query. Recuerda que la propiedad `screen` se refiere a solo pantalla y el `min-width` define desde qué tamaño y hasta el máximo de la pantalla (screen) aplica el cambio.

https://codepen.io/cesarbmolina/pen/rNaOVmZ

Te dejo la documentación para que la leas y puedas entender un poco más a profundidad.

Aquí  el código por si lo quieres replicar:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: arial;
}

.container {
  background: pink;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  text-align: center;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.size-responsive::before {
  content: ' full screem';
  margin-left: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
  color: yellow;
  background: blue;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 480px) {
  .container {
    background: black;
    color: white;
  }
  .size-responsive::before {
    content: 'desde 480px';
  }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 768px) {
  .container {
    background: orange;
  }
  .size-responsive::before {
    content: 'desde 768px';
  }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 1024px) {
  .container {
    background: olive;
  }
  .size-responsive::before {
    content: 'desde 1024px';
  }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 1600px) {
  .container {
    width: 1400px;
    margin: 0 auto;
  }
  .size-responsive::before {
    content: 'desde 1600px';
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  Resultado en resolucion <span class="size-responsive"></span>
</div>
```